# Newton's Law in Integral form

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Each of the Maxwell's equations has both an integral and differential form.  Schroedinger's equation is a differential equation and, apparently (I haven't studied it yet), Feynman's path integrals are an equivalent formulation.  Newton has got a differential equation $F = \dot p$.  Is there an equivalent integral formulation of Newton's law?  Would it even be useful if there were?

Comment: Well Newton's formula for gravity is identical to [Guass's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law#Equation_involving_E_field) for electrostatics: [Poisson's Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation#Newtonian_gravity).  I only comment because that's not exactly what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

The impulse momentum theorem would be your best answer:

$p(t) = \int_0^tf(t')dt'$

Comment: I would suggest that the it should be from $t_0$ to $t$ rather than $0$ to $t$--but I'm not sure it matters.

Comment: Sure, writing the lower limit as $t_0$ generalises the integral form as this can later be set to 0 or whatever, as necessary.

Comment: Or &p(t) = \int_{t_0}^{t} m(t')a(t') dt$ to be even more general...

Comment: @CStarAlgebra can you define your variables?  Is $t' = t$?  Is $f$ the resultant force, that is $\sum \vec F= m \vec a$?